# Understanding the Difference Between Two Capacitance Sensors

Tags: capacitance, parasitic-capacitance

I'm slowly beginning to understand more about how these work thanks to answers I have received on this site. I believe one area of confusion for me has been I've looked at two differently designed Capacitance Sensors, and I believed they were basically the same, but now I've come to think that they are not.

Chirp!

http://wemakethings.net/chirp/

Other one

http://zerocharactersleft.blogspot.ca/2011/11/pcb-as-capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor.html

From my new understanding, Chirp! is only providing one "plate" and the other version is providing two. But hopefully someone can explain this more clearly.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: More Chirp! info: https://github.com/Miceuz/PlantWateringAlarm and https://github.com/Miceuz/PlantWateringAlarm/blob/master/pics/sensor.jpg

Comment: after reading what you posted, these two sensors are identicle.  The chirp! uses the ground plane as the second plate.  "The other one" does the exact same thing.

Comment: All capacitive soil sensors follow this theory.  This exact question was asked and answered here:

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/184845/how-do-you-measure-soil-moisture-using-a-capacitive-sensor

Comment: Thanks @R.Johnson but I'm still not sure about this. Just be looking at the pictures of the two boards, it looks to me that the Chirp! has one trace that is connected on both sides. Where as the "other one" has two separate traces leading into large pads that do not connect. That's why my understanding was that Chirp! was reading between that single trace and an 'outside plate' and the "other one" was reading between the two traces on the board. But I'm not sure of course, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. Thanks again!

Comment: If you look under "Moisture sensing" in the chirp! documentation they specifically state that they use the ground plane as the second plate.  If they did not use a second plate you would not be able to sense using capacitance. . .

Comment: @R.Johnson Sorry, this might sound very simple, but where on the Chirp! example is the 'ground plane'? I think if I can visually compare it to the "other one" then I will understand better. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: it is a bit hard to see with their final product but if you look at thier "protoype" picture you will see the traces better.

Comment: @R.Johnson thanks for looking into this for me. I looked at the prototypes as you suggested and I see it now. I also took a much closer look at the current board, and I can see it on their as well. The current board is black which makes seeing anything very hard, and the only place seems to be pushed right to the edge of the board which made it hard to distinguish. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

@R. Johnson pointed out that the two designs were the same in theory, and once they pointed out how to see this it made sense.

Thank you.

Dave.